# Why does my conversion method in C continue to fail?

Tags: c

I am trying to convert from a popen pass, to a float as the final result.  I have tried converting to a char, and then into a float in every possible way I can find, however the output I have seen using printf seems to be wrong every time.  I have tried using a tostring function, as well as using a %s like in the printf function that returns the correct function, however it all seems to give me the wrong output as soon as I try to convert the output.  Should I be trying a different conversion method?

Here is the code.

```
  FILE * uname;
  char os[80];
  int lastchar;
  char n;
  uname = popen("sudo python ./return63.py", "r");
  lastchar = fread(os, 1, 80, uname);
  os[lastchar] = "\0";
  n = toString(("%s", os));
  printf("THE DIRECT OUTPUT FROM PY IS %s", os);
  printf("THE DIRECT OUTPUT For n IS %c", n);
  float ia = n - 0; 
  long p = ia - 0;
  float dd = p - 0;
  printf("Your OS is %f", dd);
```

Output from the PY is 'THE DIRECT OUTPUT FROM PY IS 63.0' , which is the correct value,
output from the n is 'THE DIRECT OUTPUT For n IS �'

output from the dd is 'Your OS is Your OS is 236.000000'

The function tostring was pulled from an answered question about how to get the output from another answered question.  I have tried with and without this code.

```
int toString(char a[]) {
  int c, sign, offset, n;

  if (a[0] == '-') {  // Handle negative integers
    sign = -1;
  }

  if (sign == -1) {  // Set starting position to convert
    offset = 1;
  }
  else {
    offset = 0;
  }

  n = 0;

  for (c = offset; a[c] != '\0'; c++) {
    n = n * 10 + a[c] - '0';
  }

   if (sign == -1) {
    n = -n;
  }

  return n;
}
```

Comment: `lastchar` is uninitialised - it looks like you used `stchar` where you should have used `lastchar` ? (Also, for future reference, you should add error checking for calls that can fail, e.g. `popen`.)

Comment: You are completly correct, I forgot I had that in there, I have been hunting for other ways to convert, and I dont have that in the correct place.  Will edit the post.  Thanks!

Comment: Please provide better example as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). There is no such variable as `stchar` within code you showed. Also `toString` function purpose is not clear to me.

Comment: The tostring was another attempt at different ways to convert the output over, the other method I have tried was using just toString(os);

Comment: Is `n` supposed to be a character or a string? Your code can't seem to make up its mind. What is `toString`? What type does it return? Also, how are you expecting `toString` to know *what* to convert to a string?

Comment: Okay, `toString` returns an `int`. I'm not sure why it's called *to*String since it converts *from* a string *to* an `int`. Don't put its return value in a `char`.

Comment: That was a result of me thinking that I had declared something incorrectly, and me trying different types to see if I had put them in wrong. I also have tried with declaring 'n' as an int, and then using the n = toString(os) however, the output is negative 27656.

Comment: `os[lastchar] = "\0";` --> `os[lastchar] = '\0';`

Comment: Why don't just use `atof`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`toString` returns an `int`, so store an `int` and output an `int`.

```
int n = toString(os);    // Also removed the obfuscating '("%s", ..)'
printf("THE DIRECT OUTPUT For n IS %d", n);
```

Also your `toString` function has undefined behavior because `sign` might be read without being initialized.

```
if (a[0] == '-') {  // Handle negative integers
    sign = -1;
    offset = 1;
}
else {
    sign = 1;
    offset = 0;
}
```

You have a potential os buffer overflow and you are not doing the null termination of os correctly:

```
lastchar = fread(os, 1, sizeof(os) - 1, uname);  // Only read one byte less
os[lastchar] = '\0'; // changed from string "\0" to char '\0'
```

And finally you are not checking the input string for digits, you are accepting every input (also the '.' in "63.0"). You might want to stop at the first non-digit character:

```
for (c = offset; !isdigit((unsigned char)a[c]); c++) {
```

Comment: After inputing the code, this is my console ouput. THE DIRECT OUTPUT For n IS -2762Your OS is -2762.000000Your OS is -2762.000000

Comment: @Johnnyman Please try again with updated code. Please also note the additional cast before calling `isdigit`.

Comment: That did it! thanks! I put a thumbs up but it didnt change due to no rep.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Johnnyman If my answer helped please accept it. You might also consider upvoting it.